# VNC style connection over ADB?

Tags: adb, vnc

Could I connect to a device over USB ADB, get a shell and then launch a VNC type graphical connection where I can use that device?

I have a android device at a customer remote premises and I want to flash a new rom then configure the device graphically, I have the flashing part covered but then I will need to be able to get the screen